# Why memory fragmentation in new process?

Tags: memory, memory-management

Help me to understand next situation.
I have windows 2003 32 bit. Start windows calculator (calc) and run utility VMMap (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/vmmap.aspx) to look memory using by calculator .

VMMap  show that free memory for this process is 
Free    2 068 224 K

and below it shows fragmentation of this free memory, see picture:
[Free memory fragmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWnXl.png)

So why does this fragmentation exist? I think that when process start, the system give to it minimun memory, and then increase it if needed. But in this picture we see reserve memory for calc, and this memory is fragmentated. Why??

Comment: I understand that some systems need to run old OS versions, but support for Windows Server 2003 ended on July 14, 2015. You should really consider moving away from that 12 year old OS. I also think this is off topic due to this is not being programming.

Comment: This is example with calculator. But in real i have my own  c# application with a such problem. The free memory is very fragmentated and OutOfMemory errors appear. So i try to  understand this problem

Comment: Ok, but always better to ask the question you want to ask instead of discussing calc. I tried to answer your fragmentation question in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is relevant to compare calc.exe with a C# application in Windows Server 2003 because most likely calc.exe was written in C++ at that time. In newer OSs like Windows 10 it would be more relevant because I think calc.exe it is a .NET application there.

.NET/C# gives you very little control over memory management because there is automatic memory management through the Garbage Collector (GC). Having come from C/C++ at the start of my career I think this is a blessing because memory leaks are so much more rare. For .NET applications that allocate non-.NET resources you still need to do some management, but the Dispose pattern (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispose_pattern) using IDisposable interface takes care of much of this pain. So unless you are allocating external resources using e.g. P/Invoke memory leaks should be rare in .NET applications.

Memory may be fragmented in .NET if many objects are allocated with different life spans because then memory gaps  may occurr when temporary objects are deallocated/garbage collected and long lived objects stay in place. But that is something which the .NET GC optimize for and defragment allocated memory to ensure there is as few gaps as possible.

I assume your real issue is the OutOfMemoryExceptions and not the fragmentation. If you are allocating lots of memory then this could be a limiting factor max memory for a 32-bit .NET application is 1.4 GB. But more likely your problem is not an actual out of memory problem. Please post a new question with details on the type of data you allocate, share your stacktrace when the OutOfMemoryExceptions exception occurr and any relevant code.